# How to hide the date for meteor server console.log?

Tags: meteor

Meteor logs the date on the server:

```
I20170615-12:55:31.560(2)? my log message
```

Is there a setting/environment variable to disable the date on the left?

Comment: Which package are you using for logging?

Comment: just plain `console.log`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you should pass `--raw-logs` as a parameter while running meteor.

Eg:

```
meteor --settings settings.json --raw-logs
```

Some information I found about this:

- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7396
- https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-test-raw-logs/26361

As masterAM suggested in the comments:

```
  --raw-logs       Run without parsing logs from stdout and stderr.
```

Comment: You can also see it listed in `meteor help run`.